# Access Device Camera with Blazor

Tags: .net-core, camera, progressive-web-apps, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor Web Assembly PWA, how do I open a devices native camera?

I am trying to write a PWA to capture and save pictures.

### EDIT

Would like to save captured images as jpeg's to Azure Blob Storage.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can achieve this with HTML input. You only need to add the attribute `capture` for opening device camera straight away.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
```

You can have a look at the full source code here:

https://github.com/mehmettahameral/Blazor-wasm-pwa-camera

and live demo here:
https://infallible-bohr-56743b.netlify.app/

--

about saving the images: it depends where do you want to save it really. If you can tell me more, I might update the solution.

Hope it helps

Comment: do i have to set any thing? it does not work for me with chrome.

Comment: @sddk you need to use your mobile device.

Comment: @AnthonyRyan thanks for the edit. You can't achieve this Blazor WASM alone, so you need to create API to call from Blazor WASM. You can create Azure Functions, for example, and save it to blob storage.

Comment: @MehmetTahaMeral 
I am using <InputFile OnChange="@OnInputFileChange" />

And OnChange event is not triggered when using camera. Any idea?
edit: Actually I don't know is it triggered but image is not uploaded like when I choose from gallery.

Comment: @MehmetTahaMeral is there a way to set it so a user can opt to take a picture OR choose from their gallery?

Comment: @zholinho  the InputFile component fires an OnChange event and passes in an InputFileChangeEventArgs that provides access to the selected file list and details about each file. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @Mike yes, there is. If you delete the `capture` attribute, it will prompt users to take a photo or select from the gallery! Both examples are on my GitHub! :)

Comment: Hello @MehmetTahaMeral in your demo project where do images that taken by camera(or chosen through file explorer) are stored?

Comment: @AllaevBekzod it's basically simple file type of input. So it's stored in that input. You need to post it under a form.

Comment: @zholinho - I stumbled about this thread when trying to accomplish the same task. I didn't change my razor page though ... So it contains the <InputFile - element that blazor introduces ... The secret of storing the files is only within the function you call OnChange 
simply use a larger maxfilesize-parameter when you read the OpenReadStream(maxfilesize).ReadAsync(buffer) - of course your buffer should be large  enough ... I found that only if the file fits in maxfilesize, it can be sent over to the server-side of blazor - and smartphones tend to make larger photos every new generation

Comment: Hello @MehmetTahaMeral, how can I upload the captured picture? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this tutorial: https://wellsb.com/csharp/aspnet/blazor-webcam-capture to capture camera device, stream the content, process an image.

Then, you can use the `Azure Blob Storage client library v12 for .NET` to upload your images to your Storage Account.

> You can find a Quickstart here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet