# Blazor Hyrid - Access Device Camera from InputFile

Tags: c#, android, .net, blazor, maui

I am attempting to using Blazor Hybrid (on MAUI) to capture an image from the camera (on Android in my case). I have been trying for awhile with no success. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63275099/access-device-camera-with-blazor) StackOverflow suggests trying the following:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
```

However, this and also:

```
<InputFile OnChange="LoadPhoto" accept="image/*" capture />
```

does not work for me in Blazor Hybrid (it does work in Blazor Server/WASM). Both result in the file picker widget opening in Android rather than the camera widget. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Blazor Hybrid. I'll just mention that if it doesn't do what you need, consider writing that access in a Maui class (instead of as part of a Razor component). I know there is some interop between the "Maui" code and the "Blazor" code. You'd have to research that.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thank you! I have considered this, but I am not sure how I could do this with an abstraction like an interface so the component doesn't need to know its being used under MAUI

Comment: Why not just use MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync? ;) That's the power of .NET MAUI Hybrid, you can just use the platform devices without having to go through browser APIs

Comment: Well, the implementation of html tags depends on the program implementing them.  If it's a Chrome browser, it should work on anything.  If it's some kind of cross-platform app, then it may not work the same on all devices.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use native access to the camera. You can communicate MAUI and the Blazor part through a object injected with DI. This way, the blazor code doesn´t know that is running in a MAUI app.
This object should have a method like "TakePicture()" that you call in Blazor when clicking a button and rises an event like "OnTakePicture". The MAUI part should attach an event handler to OnTakePicture, so it can take a picture with the camera. When the picture is taken, you do the oposite way to get the picture as a byte[] and show it.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it as follows:

1. Create a button and an image element in your razor file:

   ```
   <button @onclick="CaptureImage">Capture Image</button>
   <img id="image" />
   ```
2. Add the `CaptureImage` function:

   ```cs
   public async Task CaptureImage()
   {
       FileResult photo = null;
       if (DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.WinUI || DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.MacCatalyst)
       {
           photo = await FilePicker.PickAsync();
       }
       else if (DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android || DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
       {
           photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
       }

       if (photo == null)
       {
           return;
       }

       using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
       {
           var dotnetImageStream = new DotNetStreamReference(stream);
           await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("jsFunctions.captureImage", "image", dotnetImageStream);
       }

   }
   ```
3. Implement the JavaScript function in your js file:

   ```js
   window.jsFunctions = {
    captureImage: async function (imageId, imageStream) {
        const arrayBuffer = await imageStream.arrayBuffer();
        const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        document.getElementById(imageId).src = url;
        document.getElementById(imageId).style.display = 'block';
        return true;
    },
   }
   ```